# How to make a `List` with different items in row count?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

`Grid` doesn't fit because I need `WindowScroller` and they doesn't work together.

I already have 3 nodes in row for `dir`
but I need to have 6 nodes in row for `file`

`dir` and `file` can't be in the same row, instead must be whitespace (check out screen shots)

I've tried to switch 3 or 6 `nodesInRow` with `isDir` flag and track actual `nodes` indexed as increment after each of actual put-node-in-row but it didn't work because of reRenders that start's not from `rowInd = 0`

actual:
https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/04/10/Screen-Shot-2019-04-10-at-5.57.30-PMa278117232cc829d.png

expected:
https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/04/11/Screen-Shot-2019-04-11-at-1.19.57-PM.png

P.S. Sorry for direct img links ... it's because of 'You need at least 10 reputation to post images.'

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how I wanted it to work

https://codesandbox.io/s/lpvn23vz7